# How to prioritize events in SharePoint 2010 calendar?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, calendar

I was wandering if it is possible to prioritiaze events in calendar. For example, I have created an additional element in list (using calendars overlay), which has 3 options: A,B,C, and A >B and C. If I order a date 11-08-2016 9:00 for A, I don't want B or C to be able to get into the same date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of fonctionnality don't exist in the OOTB of SharePoint. You must dev it !
You can use Event Receiver on your Calendar list (on item Adding) and DEV your "check" logic. To do this you must use Visual Studio.